# Array integer Android

Tags: android, arrays, android-edittext, textview

ok so i create an array that has integers. The array displays five number from the min and max. How can i display all five numbers in a textview or edittext ? I tried:

```
nameofile.setText(al.get(x).toString());
```

but it only displays one?

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = minint; i <= maxint; i++)
    al.add(i);

Random ran = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int x = al.remove(ran.nextInt(al.size()));
    String myString = TextUtils.join(", ", al);
    lottonumbers.setText(myString);
```

Comment: It only displays one element because that is all you are accessing.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.add(0);
    al.add(1);
    al.add(5);
    al.add(4);
    al.add(3);
    java.util.Collections.sort(al);//for sorting Integer values

    String listString = "";

    for (int s : al)
    {
        listString += s + " ";
    }
    nameofile.setText(listString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently only printing out one element (the one at index `x`). If you want to print them all in order, you can just join them using [`TextUtils.join()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable%29).

**Update**: After seeing your edit, I think there's a better way to go about what you're trying to do. Instead of trying to pull the values one at a time, and update the list, why not just shuffle them, then use the above method?

**Update 2**: Okay, I think I finally understand your problem. Just a simple change, then.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = minint; i <= maxint; i++)
    al.add(i);

Random ran = new Random();

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(); // Create a builder
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int x = al.remove(ran.nextInt(al.size()));
    if (i > 0)
        text.append(", "); // Add a comma if we're not at the start
    text.append(x);
}
lottonumbers.setText(text);
```

Comment: but I put it to where the numbers are random? which is x. Sorry new to android and coding

Comment: I don't know what `x` is, it's defined in your code. You're currently showing the `x`th item using `.get(x)`. The above will show all elements in the array.

Comment: but isn't your code going to show all 100 number if the max is 100. Im only trying to pull five numbers out of 100. any idea? I found a way but every time I click the button again it doesnt reset the value and prints another set of numbers right next to the prevoius one

Comment: @marcusmofo Ooooooooooookay, I finally get your problem. :) I've updated my answer again.

Comment: Problem Solve wow thanks man. I will eventually be on your level of coding.
thanks alot

Comment: @marcusmofo Glad to hear it! Don't forget to click the checkmark next to answer if it solves your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

al.get(x).toString() will only get the value at index "x". If you want to display all values, you need to combine all of the values from the array into a single string then use setText on that string.

Comment: so something like this.
String num = (" " + x);
then use the method I was using ?

Comment: say you have an array of 3 numbers e.g. al = [1, 2, 3]. if you call al.get(0), it will return the first number from the array -- 1. so String num = (" " + x); will not produce the result you are looking for. What you would need to do for the above example is String num = al.get(0) + " " + al.get(1) + " " + al.get(2)... and so on. A for loop is suitable for this purpose. e.g. 
String num = "";

for(int x=0;x<al.length;x++) { num += " " + al.get(x); } 

nameoffile.setText(num);

Answer (score 0):

You are only showing one number of your array in the TextView, you must to concat the numbers to see the others results like:

```
for(Integer integer : al) {
  nameofile.setText(nameofile.getText() + " " + al.get(x).toString());
}
```

Then i think you can show all number in one String.